# Error: Cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'

Tags: c++, arrays

I am taking an input from user for the size of an array, and then the elements of it.

In the below code, `cin>>A[i]` in the first `for` loop is giving me an error.

From other questions similar to this one, it's a simple operator error, and the script is similar to working three dimensional ones I've seen. Is `new` creating a 3 dimensional array by default, meaning I'd need to define columns too? If not, where would I be missing the operator?

```
int** A;
int s;
cin >> s;
A = new int*[s];

for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    A[i]=new int[s];
    cout<< "Enter value: ";
    cin>>A[i];
}

cout<< "Array:\n";
for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
{
    cout << A[j] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A[]` is an `int*` pointer, not an `int` value.

There is no `operator>>` that can read an `int` value into an `int*` pointer.  Since you want to read an `int` value, you have to read into an `int` variable, so change `A[i]` in your 1st loop to `*A[i]` instead:

```
cin >> *A[i];
```

You need to do the same with `A[j]` in the 2nd loop:

```
cout << *A[j] << " ";
```

This is because there is no `operator<<` to write an `int` value from an `int*` pointer, but there is an `operator<<` that can write the value of a memory address held by a `void*` pointer, and `int*` is implicitly convertible to `void*`.

Don't forget to `delete[]` your arrays when you are done with them:

```
int s;
cin >> s;

int** A = new int*[s];    
for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    A[i] = new int[s];

for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
{
    cout << "Enter value: ";
    cin >> *A[i];
}

cout << "Array:\n";
for(int j = 0; j < s; ++j)
    cout << *A[j] << " ";

for(int j = 0; j < s; ++j)
    delete[] A[j];
delete[] A;
```

That being said, you are wasting memory for the second dimension when `s > 1`, since you are filling in and using only the 1st column and ignoring additional columns.  The code you showed only really needs a 1-dimensional array instead:

```
int s;
cin >> s;

int* A = new int[s];

for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
{
    cout << "Enter value: ";
    cin >> A[i];
}

cout << "Array:\n";
for(int j = 0; j < s; ++j)
    cout << A[j] << " ";

delete[] A;
```

If you really want a 2-dimensional array, try something more like this instead:

```
int rows, columns;
cin >> rows;
cin >> columns;

int** A = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    A[i] = new int[columns];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        cout << "Enter value for (" << i << "," << j << "): ";
        cin >> A[i][j];
    }
}

cout << "Array:\n";
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    delete A[i];
delete[] A;
```

That being said, you really should be using `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that now, I had assumed that initializing it in the loop would mean I wouldn't have to use pointer notation afterwards, but I can see now that the new array isn't initialized on creation.

Answer (score 0):

What array do you want to create? Two-dimensional SxS, or just S-sized?
Because you are creating an array of arrays, while trying to access it as a single-dimensional.

Changing `int** A` to `int* A`, `A = new int*[s]` to `A = new int[s]`, and getting rid of `A[i]=new int[s]` in the first loop makes the code correct.